# Meteor: Uncaught TypeError: Meteor.users is not a function

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts

On a site running Meteor. Through Google chrome console I can run:

```
Meteor.user()
```

This returns what's needed for my logged in account.

When I run

```
Meteor.users()
```

It returns

```
VM596:1 Uncaught TypeError: Meteor.users is not a function
```

Please could someone advise?

Answer (score 3):

**Meteor.users** is a mongo collection containing all user documents. So you cannot do Meteor.users(). Rather you can find documents in there using

```
Meteor.users.find({}).fetch();
```

For further information you can see [meteor docs](http://docs.meteor.com/api/accounts.html)

Comment: Thanks - tried that but it's just bring me back rather than everyone else.

Comment: I could not understand you. Did the answer help??

Comment: The code you wrote just brings back one user rather than everyone in the system

Comment: You can access all the users in the server side only. If you need all users in the client side you need to publish those data from server and then subscribe it.

Comment: Have you removed the autopublish??

Comment: It's a work based system that I have not go server access to as yet. Just getting a single user is fine

Answer (score 2):

You have to include the following package in package.js to get Meteor.users to run

`accounts-password@1.3.3`